# Migration to Play 2.5.3 - Crypto library deprecated but also perhaps broken?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Currently receiving this error while trying to move an application to 2.5.3

```
Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: The global crypto instance requires a running application!
```

Am wading through close to 1000 errors (reported so far - once I clear a batch then low and behold yet another batch show up so there could be lots more)

I can't seem to get a handle on how to fix this particular one however. The migration guide indicates that the library is deprecated and will be removed and offers replacement paths -- none of which appear trivial -- but it doesn't indicate how to get the library instantiated with the need for the running Application.

Did find some chatter in github issues but nothing specific to the actual problem.

All I need (right now) is `Crypto.encryptAES` and `Crypto.decryptAES` replacements if the library can't be properly started if a quick sub is possible.

This problem currently stops Play dead in it's tracks btw so I have no idea what comes next once I get past this issue.

DI would supposedly handle this and yet it obviously doesn't.

Here is relevant portion of stack trace I'm seeing:

`1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:400)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:158)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The global crypto instance requires a running application!
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at play.api.libs.Crypto$$anonfun$crypto$1.apply(Crypto.scala:56)
    at play.api.libs.Crypto$$anonfun$crypto$1.apply(Crypto.scala:56)
    at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158)
    at play.api.libs.Crypto$.crypto(Crypto.scala:57)
    at play.api.libs.Crypto$.encryptAES(Crypto.scala:78)`

I used that to find this: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.3/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/Crypto.scala in the hopes that it might shed some light but I'm still at a loss as to how to address.

Comment: FYI: You would think that the Play document that tells you your at the end of the rope with one library might actually be kind enough to tell you how to actually install the next one...

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you are using `Crypto.encryptAES` as a static method from outside of Play.  That uses a global instance, which needs a running application because it uses applicationCache().  (Incidentally, this is why Play is removing static methods and global state whereever possible, because it is possible to get into states like this where a method is called with no application.)

In any case, `Crypto` is a wrapper around three other classes. What you want to do is instantiate a `AESCTRCrypter`, which has `encryptAES`.

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.3/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/crypto/Crypto.scala#L350

This uses a CryptoConfig, which you'll get from CryptoConfigParser:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.3/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/crypto/Crypto.scala#L463

which will take an Environment and a Configuration -- these have lots of docs and factory methods on them so I won't go into details there.

Once you've done that, you can create your own wrapper class with a static method.

However, AESCTRCrypter is also deprecated, because this is not a secure use of symmetric encryption.  Because it is deprecated and insecure, it will go away in a future version of Play, and then those compilation errors will be permanent and you will have to write your own replacement symmetric encryption code if you want to maintain AES-CTR without modification.

The recommended libraries are listed in the migration guide, and there's an example project at https://github.com/playframework/play-kalium.

In addition, there is an AES library called JNCryptor that is available on Maven, recommended by CossackLabs: https://cossacklabs.com/choose-android-crypto.html

https://github.com/RNCryptor/JNCryptor

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cryptonode.jncryptor</groupId>
    <artifactId>jncryptor</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>`

EDIT: As of 2018, I recommend you use [Google Tink](https://github.com/google/tink).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple AES symmetric encryption examples in Scala that you could replace Play's Crypto with:
https://gist.github.com/alexandru/ac1c01168710786b54b0
https://gist.github.com/sapardi/2828070

Comment: Thanks James -- that gave me enough to get the site running -- now onto the next batch of warnings (plus I think anorm just trashed the database... yes I know there's a slick answer of that too...)

Comment: Hi James -- the examples you linked use AES/ECB, which is not secure, and which is also not what Play 2.4.x uses, so even if they compile, they probably won't encrypt and decrypt properly.

Comment: Thanks @WillSargent.  Are there any secure options for symmetric encryption on the JVM which you can get from Maven Central?